# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions called twice

Tags: ios, core-data

I attached the two thread calling the method that shall always run on the main thread:

[image: Main Thread]

[image: The Background Thread]

This is causing a crash as I am trying to create a persistent store coordinator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack was misleading. The crash has nothing to do with didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. The core data model has a wrong inverse relationship. As I search more, I found out the queue: com.apple.root.default-... is created whenever there is something wrong at launch like extensive memory loading. Anyhow, fixing the inverse relationship fixed it.

The symbols Xcode throw at me and unclear crash reason say there is a lot waiting to reach a more productive development environment.